# Помогите написать запрос в базу (PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня есть две таблицы user и user_schedule_activity.
Мне нужно вставить в user_schedule_activity некоторую запись для user,  у которых нету этой самой записи. 
Например это запись должна выглядеть вот так:

```
id - uuid_generate_v4() (случайный uuid),
end - '2070-01-01 00:00:00.000000',
start - '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000',
user_id - "user".id (id для user у которого нету этой записи)
work_activity_id - '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
```

Написал запрос

```
INSERT INTO "user_schedule_activity"
    (id, "end", START, user_id, work_activity_id)
SELECT uuid_generate_v4(),
       '2070-01-01 00:00:00.000000',
       '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000',
       "user".id,
       '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
FROM "user"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "user_schedule_activity" ON ("user".id = "user_schedule_activity".user_id)
WHERE "user_schedule_activity".user_id ISNULL;
```

К сожалению, он не выполняет свою задачу.

Comment: А проблема то в чем? что не получается?

Comment: @Viktorov, Я вроде написал, но он не выполняет свою задачу.

INSERT INTO "user_schedule_activity" (id, "end", start, user_id, work_activity_id)
  SELECT
    uuid_generate_v4(),
    '2070-01-01 00:00:00.000000',
    '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000',
    "user".id,
    '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
  FROM "user" LEFT OUTER JOIN "user_schedule_activity"
      ON ("user".id = "user_schedule_activity".user_id)
  WHERE "user_schedule_activity".user_id ISNULL;

Comment: Что значит "не выполняет?". Данные не вставляются? Вставляются не те? Приведите пример в данных, где он не работает. Сейчас кажется, что у вас правильный запрос и все должно работать

Comment: Данные вообще не вставляются, запрос просто не находит куда их вставлять, скорее всего я написал кривой JOIN

Comment: а select возвращает результат?

Comment: Нет, не возвращает

Comment: Так возможно у вас нет ни 1 строки `user` для которой в  `user_schedule_activity` отсутствует связь?

Comment: Есть, стоит NOT NULL

Comment: Где стоит? О чем вы? То есть, по какой причине вы вообще решили, что у вас сейчас в таблице не хватает строчек?

Comment: Я ещё не очень дружу с SQL, сейчас я пытаюсь написать просто SELECT который покажет мне всех user у которых нету нужной мне записи user_schedule_activity (пример я писал выше). Но у меня не выходит, хотя я уверен что такие user существуют в базе.

Comment: НА мой взгляд ваш запрос был написан правильно, и если он ничего не показывает, то таких данных нет. Повторюсь, почему вы уверены, что такие данные есть?

Comment: А то где вы выполняете свой запрос умеет показывать ошибки ? `ISNULL` в самом конце вообще пишется раздельно `IS NULL`, если у вас написано так как показано, то оно должно было дать синтаксическую ошибку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запрос выбирает только тех юзеров, у которых вообще нет никакой активности. Уточните запрос, чтобы выбирались юзеры, у которых нет какой-то определённой активности. Например:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN "user_schedule_activity" ON "user".id = user_schedule_activity".user_id AND "user_schedule_activity".type_of_activity='ЛЕЖАТЬ НА ДИВАНЕ'
```